# Identificar Visitante e Usuário no Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugin

Estou trabalhando em um plugin wordpress, e necessito alterar o nome do menu **Login** para **Minha conta** quando o usuário estiver logado.

Também necessito de alterar o titulo da página. Já tentei usar o filtro abaixo, mas acaba alterando todos os links do site.

`add_filter('the_title', 'function_name');`

e quanto alterar o nome do menu, não encontrei nada a respeito, alguém tem alguma sugestão sobre algo?

Obrigado desde já...

**O CÓDIGO**

Tentando adicionar um shortcode para ser usado da forma citada acima!

```php
if ( !function_exists('custom_login_form') )
{
    function custom_login_form()
    {
        $args=array(
            "echo" => false,
            "label_log_in" => "Entrar",
            "remember"  => true,
        );
        if ( !is_user_logged_in() ){
            return wp_login_form($args);
        }else{
            return 'Logado em Minha conta! <br />' . wp_loginout('index.php');
        }
    }
}
add_shortcode('login_form', 'custom_login_form');
```

Isto funciona perfeitamente, gostaria agora fazer as alterações no menu e no titulo da página!

**RESOLUÇÃO**

Depois de muitas pesquisas conseguir encontrar uma solução para o problema, que por coincidência eu já tinha tentado e não funcionou de jeito nenhum.

Usando o seguinte filtro.

```php
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'function_name', 10, 2);
function func_name_wp_nav($items, $args){
    return $items;
}
```

Então você adicionando items de acordo o menu, que geralmente é **LI** ele adiciona como último elemento, exemplo.

```
$item .= "<li><a href='#'>Item 1</a></li>";
```

Isto funcionou perfeitamente pra mim! Qualquer dúvida com relação ao post, comentem e tentarei responder no que souber.

Obrigado...

Answer (score 1):

Você deve estar procurando usar a função [`is_user_logged_in()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in), se o usuário estiver logado o valor de retorno é *verdadeiro*, caso contrário é *falso*.

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // Fazer algo quando esse usuário estiver logado
} else {
    // Fazer algo caso seja um visitante
}
```

Sobre a segunda pergunta, a função [`the_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) deveria funcionar, entretanto se preferir usar algo mais *clean*, use [`the_title_attribute`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title_attribute), ambas tem praticamente o mesmo objetivo, porem, essa última tem um parâmetro a mais que é `$post` que permite especificar o [*ID* ou objeto](http://codex.wordpress.org/How_to_Pass_Tag_Parameters#Integer_or_object) de uma postagem, podendo obter ou alterar, por padrão a postagem atual é buscada.

Para alterar o nome do menu, [**aqui**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9211/changing-admin-menu-labels) (*Changing Admin Menu Labels* - WordPress Development SE) têm uma solução que talvez funciona para você.

Comment: **@QMechanic73** A função `is_user_logged_in()` está correta, eu já estava tentando com ela, porém o que não consigo é fazer que altere o menu e o titulo da página corretamente, quando alterado o titulo da página, é alterado todos os outros links também. E quanto alterar o link na barra principal, não consegui e o link que passou é referente aos menus da administração. Obrigado!

Comment: @ItaloIzaac Vamos por partes =D. O título, tente fazer uma expressão condicional usando [`in_the_loop()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_the_loop) para verificar se o contexto de `the_title`(*já que `the_title_attribute` parece não ser preciso aqui*) está dentro do loop.

Comment: **@QMechanic** Usando o `in_the_loop()` funcionou perfeitamente modificando o titulo da página sem modificar outros links da mesma. Agora a segunda parte é "MACABRA", rsrs, obrigado desde já...

Comment: A mesma ideia passada pelo post é a mesma logica para essa aqui, porém a solução apresentada não funciona e aparentemente está incorreta.